# Assassins Creed Brotherhood. Infiltrate pantheon by top?

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

In the current memory i am in a mission where it says  Infiltrate pentheon by top. But do not find a way how to climb in top of the pantheon. I also tried it earlier because there is a viewpoint up there?

So, is there a way to climb up there? I already walking surrounding of the pantheon to find out a way up. But no help :(

Comment: Which memory/mission is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the pantheon from the rear left-side. You can jump from a building to a ledge. Then go to the middle of the building and climb up. As easy as 1-2-3.

Comment: Yup, there are 'knobs' on the ceiling (on the inside!) you can grab and climb through the hole.

Answer (score 0):

After hours i have found it. You have to first complete the Leonardo's mission to have the parachute the climbing up to nearby cross and jump with the parachute to go to the top of the pantheon.

Enjoy! :D

Comment: The parachute is not needed, there's a building nearby from where you can jump to a climbable surface in the midsection of the Pantheon.

Comment: @Wilerson: will try that!